# Missing the "Create" tab for creating splines

Tags: interface

Im learning blender on my own, and have a problem.
I am trying to learn how to use the spline tool, but tutorials have a menu I do not by default.

[image]

[image]

The top picture is what I see, and the bottom is what the tutorials have. I have enabled the addon that allows for splines, and I had the menu previously and was able to create splines. I dont know what changed between then and now.
edit: I installed blender on a different computer, and the create menu showed up when I enabled an addon. When I enable the addon on my laptop, the create menu does not show up. I dont understand why this is happening

Comment: Same Blender version on both computers?

Comment: Hello :). This can have multiple reasons, and you didn't provide a lot of info, so it's just guessing. Maybe you just disabled add-ons in the Workspace tab: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/173831/78972